# Printing simple text using .net Maui Windows10

Tags: c#, .net, printing, windows-10, maui

I wanted to print texts using .net Maui app. How can i achive this.

I tried using PrintManager class  but i do not understand how i can set string(text) to print using this class or i don not understand how to use PrintManager class.

```
printMan = PrintManager.GetForCurrentView();//How do i make it for simple string to print
printMan.PrintTaskRequested += PrintTaskRequested;

// Build a PrintDocument and register for callbacks
printDoc = new PrintDocument();
printDocSource = printDoc.DocumentSource;
printDoc.Paginate += Paginate;
printDoc.GetPreviewPage += GetPreviewPage;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Windows applications built with .NET MAUI use the Windows UI 3 (WinUI 3) library to create native applications for the Windows desktop. I found a github issue: "[Printing in WinUI 3 Desktop](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/4419#top:~:text=%40marb2000%20has%20an%20app%20with%20a%20printing%20sample%20you%20can%20find%20here%3A%20https%3A//github.com/marb2000/PrintSample)", in which someone provided a printing example, you can try to refer to it.

Answer (score 0):

I manage to do it by Socket class.

1. Create partial class "PrintService" and partial method
   "public partial async Task PrintSticker(string ip, int port, List
   linesToPrtint)"
   Refer this link [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-
   integration/invoke-platform-code?view=net-maui-7.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/invoke-platform-code?view=net-maui-7.0)
2. Implement the method in platform partial class as below

   ```
   public partial async Task PrintSticker(string ip, int port, List<string> 
   linesToPrtint)
   {
       //Task.Delay(1000);
       Socket pSocket = new Socket(SocketType.Stream, 
       ProtocolType.IP);
       pSocket.SendTimeout = 1500;
       await pSocket.ConnectAsync(ip, port);
       List<byte> otBytes= new List<byte>();
       foreach(var text in linesToPrtint)
       {
           otBytes.AddRange(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text));
           otBytes.Add(0x0A);
       }
       await pSocket.SendAsync(otBytes.ToArray());
       pSocket.Close();
   }
   ```
3. Access the methode as below

   ```
   PrintService printService  = new PrintService();
   await printService.PrintSticker("x.x.x.x", 9100, new List<string> { "Test Text"});
   ```